# Splash screen between two activities

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want to show a splash screen between my first and second activity. Both the activities make use of AsyncTask. First being a simple login screen retrieving data for the whole app and second loads the activity specific data. Currently, both the activities have their own ProgressDialogs which is quite naive but they were developed individually and then I wasn’t planning to put them one after the other.

I tried to implement the splash screen only replace a loading process from one activity. But, in order to place a splash screen in between them do I have to transfer all the loading process to a single activity? Which activity should contain the code for the splash screen? I basically want to replace two `ProgressDialog`s by a single splash screen. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would just make a transitional activity that displays a splash screen, preloads the data for the next activity, then launches the next activity.

Activity A loads Activity B which shows the splash screen while simultaneously running the AsyncTask. Once the AsyncTask completes load Activity C.

I hope I understand your question correctly :-)

Comment: I thought of that. I wasn't sure If I should make a new activity only to load data. Anyway I'll try that.

Comment: You could instead launch an AsyncTask from Activity A: 

In onPreExecute(), display a fullscreen bitmap. In doInBackground(), do your asynchronous preloading of data. In onProgressUpdate(), update the image's appearance. Finally, in onPostExecute() call the second activity.

Comment: The problem is there are two loading processes post loading for activity A and pre-loading for activity C. I want to show a splash screen for the combined loading process. How do I access the same splash Dialog across activities?